# How to click on a custom attribute in selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, nodes

I have this following html: 
which has a class and a custom attribute, I have several header's with the same className. I wanted to know how to uniquely get this element and click on it.

```
<h4 class="font-white topic-heading progress-header no-margin width-80 d-table-cell" data-collapse-id="1">I. Introduction</h4>
```

This is what i tried:-

I tried to get the attribute of the class="font-white..." with data-collapse-id="1" :

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='font-white topic-heading progress-header no-margin width-80 d-table-cell']")).getAttribute('data-collapse-id="1"');
console.log(element); // this prints a promise.

element.click(); //element.click is not a function exception
```

I also tried:-

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-collapse-id='1']"));

element.click(); // element.click is not a function exception.
```

I wanted to know how to fetch this element in selenium and click on it.

this is the entire div:

```
<div class="page-width d-table topic-heading-div">
   <h4 class="font-white topic-heading progress-header no-margin width-80 d-table-cell" data-collapse-id="1">I. Introduction</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-check font-white font-18 width-20 d-table-cell text-center vertical-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: "h4" is a header tag and not clickable (to my knowledge).  What HTML code follows that line?

Comment: I have added the entire div in my answer thanks.

Comment: Add /I to the end of your xpath.  I believe that will work

Comment: That should be lower case (auto-correct)

Comment: to the first one or the second one: something like this :                              var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-collapse-id='1']/I"));

Comment: Either will work but it should be /i

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:  I added /i at the end of the xpath:                                                       var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-collapse-id='1']/i")).click();

Comment: Then it would seem that h4 is a web element while "i" is not. Just the same, I do not think that h4 is a clickable element, just header text. What would clicking this on the page do? Do you know how to use browser tools to determine xpath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4[data-collapse-id='1']")).click();
```

Finding element through this attribute should work because this is unique. Also it sometimes unable to click on element found by xpath. I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

It seem that your `element` variable intends to return [*attribute*](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp). However, [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method should receive attribute name value as argument and return an attribute value which is a simple string... And here you got few problems:

- you're trying to pass wrong argument: `'data-collapse-id="1"'` instead of `'data-collapse-id'`
- attribute value, a string, is not clickable!

Simple answer to your question- **there is no way you can click on a custom attribute**

Answer (score 0):

Class is meant to define a group of elements having similar features. In this case, the `topic-heading` class is used to group the `<h4>` tags alongwith a unique ID attribute called as `data-collapse-id`. But in such case's we can't use ID to identify/specify each web element as the elements of same class can be hundreds/thousands.

You can try locating **any** header element uniquely using the following ways:

```
var exactHeadingText = "I. Introduction"; // Exact heading
By locExactTopicHeading = By.xpath("//h4[contains(@class,'topic-heading') and text()='"+ exactHeadingText + "']");

var partialHeadingText = "Introduction"; // Partial heading
By locPartialTopicHeading = By.xpath("//h4[contains(@class,'topic-heading') and contains(text(),'"+ partialHeadingText + "')]");
```

Ideally you should pass the `exactHeadingText/partialHeadingText` as a function parameter/argument so that the code can be reused to fetch any topic heading.

You can then use `findElement()` and perform any operation on it.