# Selenium find all custom named tags

Tags: python, selenium

How can I find all custom HTML tags named `job-title-text` and it's value(s) `Sr Manager`  using Selenium in Python? The tag appears multiple times with different values throughout my HTML.

Here's how my HTML looks like:

```
<a ph-tevent="job_click" ref="linkEle" href.bind="getUrl(linkEle, 'job', eachJob, '', eachJob.jobUrl)" data-ph-at-id="job-link" data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page20-CRUCUZ" job-title-text="Sr Manager" data-ph-at-job-post-date-text="2021-11-23T00:00:00.000Z">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on a custom attribute in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034317/how-to-click-on-a-custom-attribute-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all web elements containing `job-title-text` attribute

```py
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@job-title-text]")
```

This will give you all web elements containing `job-title-text` attribute with value equals to `Sr Manager`

```py
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@job-title-text='Sr Manager']")
```